# How to set the command buttons on ECB menu for multiple List templates in SharePoint newlook using SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have created spfx addin which will displays the command text on the SharePoint custom list. But i want that it should be displays in all the different SharePoint list templates for e.g Document Library, Issue tracking, Picture Library, calendar event etc.

Here is my XML file code:

[image]

Can anyone suggest the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution.

We just have to repeat the  tag as many templates we have to set the command button on ECB as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

We just have to change the RegistrationId as our "listBaseTemplate" Id and remaining attributes will be same as you can see in the above screenshot "100" is the CustomList, "101" is the DocumentLibrary and so on.